# Sass caching my mixin but only in one place

Tags: css, sass

I am relatively new to Sass, and I am using a mixin for retina versions of images.

In one place in my stylesheet, is is generating an old version of the mixin.

This is my mixin

```
@mixin retina(){
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
        @content;
    }
}
```

This is a working Sass include

```
background:url(/img/yt-icon-grey.png) left center no-repeat;    
@include retina(){
    background:url(/img/yt-icon-grey-retina.png) left center no-repeat; 
    @include vendor(background-size, 22px 20px);
}
```

Which outputs

```
background: url(/img/yt-icon-grey.png) left center no-repeat; }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
    .footer-social .footer-yt {
        background: url(/img/yt-icon-grey-retina.png) left center no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: 22px 20px;
        -moz-background-size: 22px 20px;
        -ms-background-size: 22px 20px;
        -o-background-size: 22px 20px;
        background-size: 22px 20px; } }
```

As expected

But this one, seemingly the same

```
background:url(/img/telephone-icon.png) left center no-repeat;  
padding-left:20px;  
@include retina(){
    background:url(/img/telephone-icon-retina.png) left center no-repeat;   
    @include vendor(background-size, 17px 20px);
}
```

outputs differently

```
background: url(/img/telephone-icon.png) left center no-repeat;
padding-left: 20px; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
    .main-header .telephone {
        background: url(/img/telephone-icon-retina.png) left center no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: 17px 20px;
        -moz-background-size: 17px 20px;
        -ms-background-size: 17px 20px;
        -o-background-size: 17px 20px;
        background-size: 17px 20px; } }
```

I have deleted my sass-cache folder, and the compiled file. But it still compiles this way.
I have also tried changing the class name (.telephone to .tel) but it still compiles wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with the output?  Also, you're generating prefixes unnecessarily.  The only browser that actually needs prefixes is Android (see:  http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size).

Comment: You are quite correct, I have just realised it is working as expected due to it being nested within a width based media query. The problem I am having is I am using respond.js to provide support to IE < 9, and this seems to be reading this media query and showing the retina image.
In vanilla CSS I have got around this by removing the "only screen" but can't do that in this instance. Back to the drawing board I suspect.
Also, on your prefixing point, I am using the latest version of inuitcss. The vendor mixin does the prefixing. I presume it is for users who have older versions of browsers.

Comment: Except that you're blindly throwing in prefixes, even if the browser has *never* had prefixes to begin with (IE never has... and the versions of Opera and Firefox that did are so ancient, you may as well ignore them).  [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) doesn't do this:  it provides only the prefixes that are relevant to the property.

Comment: I don't think thats really an argument you need to be having with me. I am sure the developer of inuitcss would welcome your feedback.

Comment: Back on topic. I have solved this problem by editing the framework to have an "IE" mode. This mode doesn't generate any media queries, instead pulling out the desktop only styles. Whilst also ignoring retina styles. As described here - http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie/
I have issued a pull request to inuit to reflect this change too.